Stein's method for exchangeable sequence
I have a random (not i.i.d.) sequence that I can show is an exchangeable pair.
I am trying to apply relatively recent ideas in Berry-Esseen bounds to the problem (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-1966-2_2) to show convergence on the same order as if they were i.i.d. with the same variance.
I have these questions:
1.) In my random sequence each random variable is a function of two independent random variables. (Say $Z_i = X_i+Y_i$) $X_i$ has a dependence on previous realizations of $X$ but $Y_i$ is i.i.d.
2.) Is it appropriate to define my sequence as a random permutation of just $Y$s?
3.) If I then define my exchangeable random variable I find that $W$ and $W^*$ are independent.  This is a problem in assumption (2.1) of the above link as I would need to scale the R with $\lambda$ in the above?  Is it necessary then to limit the number of permutations of $Y$s?
....
As I type this out I realize that what I have is a sequence of non-identical but independent random variables, which might be a much easier way of going about the problem.
